# Using Flask to reproduce an audio using json

Tags: python, flask, postman, text-to-speech, gtts

i'm trying to make an app in flask-python that using a json post send an audio using the gtts google library as the answer, but my method doesn't work. My code is the following.

```
from gtts import gTTS
from flask import Flask, send_file, request



app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def t2s():
    text = request.get_json()
    obj = gTTS(text = text, slow = False, lang = 'en')    
    obj.save('audio.wav')
    return send_file('audio.wav')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=3000  , debug=True, use_reloader=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

any suggestions?, i'm using postman.

Thanks a lot for the possible help

Comment: (You really need a better explanation of what goes wrong than "doesn't work"!)  What does your JSON data look like?  It could quite easily be something that isn't appropriate as the `text=` parameter to `gTTS()`.

Comment: what means `doesn't work`? We can't read in your mind and don't expect that we will run code to see how it works. Besides it can works correctly on our computers.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you want to send `POST` to this Flask then you have to use `@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])` to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Flask` as default doesn't get `POST` requests and you have to use `methods=['POST', 'GET']`

```
from gtts import gTTS
from flask import Flask, send_file, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def t2s():
    text = request.get_json()
    print(text)
    obj = gTTS(text = text, slow = False, lang = 'en')    
    obj.save('audio.wav')
    return send_file('audio.wav')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=3000)
```

And test (using `mplayer` on Linux):

```
import requests
import os

data = 'Hello World'

r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/', json=data)

open('output.wav', 'wb').write(r.content)

os.system('mplayer output.wav')
```

Comment: this works, sorry for the hazing in the question, next time i will be more specific